# vagrant - Windows 7 Permission denied

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant

I am trying to set up a Vagrant box but am running into a Permission Denied error on Windows. I am able to successfully download and create a box but when it tries to import the box the error is thrown. The Vagrantfile is good as I am able to get the box to start up and run correctly with Mac OSX and Ubuntu. I have been using the install packages provided by Vagrant. I have tried running Command Prompt as administrator but still had no luck.

Comment: Can you try to enable VAGRANT debug level and get the trace to see more on whats happening?

Comment: And btw http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/debugging.html to enable the debug